# import data from xcel sheet to mysql database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have  a requirement to fill the table in mysql database from an uploaded xlsheet from the front end in asp.net. how do i do this?
is there any efficient way to fill the bulk data into table as in sql server instead of reading row by row?

Answer (score 0):

Try command line [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) featute in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). It allows to read excel files directly (without COM interfaces) and uses bulk insert.

Firstly, you can test this in GUI wizard.

Comment: sorry i want to do that at runtime in a asp.net web application. some thing like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToDataBase.aspx. read data from xls to a data table and then fill the mysql table at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in mysql command promt window!

load data local infile 'file name path' into table tablename lines terminated by '\n' enclosed by '"' fields terminated by ';'(field1,field2,...);